# How to use android UI controls under native C++ code

Tags: android

THE QUESTION is how to reuse the android text edit control, which is java, in our software (C++).

Here is some background:

My company's gps software is written in c++ (agg for ui rendering), it can run under iOS, Android and WinCE/Windows. But for now our main focus is android.

Now we need a text edit UI element, we are considering using android ui elements instead of reinventing it ourselves.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use GUI elements which are part of the SDK in the NDK. You can use OpenGL to draw whatever you need if you need an all c++ app.

You can, however, build a sdk based UI layer on top of your app and use JNI to call your underlying c code. Check out this tutorial for a sample:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/